Sequelize cascade delete not deleting associated records when parent record is deleted
Sequelize cascade delete not deleting associated records when parent record is deleted
I'm encountering an issue with Sequelize where cascade delete behavior is not working as expected. I have a database structure with multiple tables (Projects, Banners, Images, Points, and Thumbnails), and I've defined associations between them to enable cascade delete when a parent record is deleted.
Here's the database structure:

I have correctly defined associations between the models in Sequelize and specified onDelete: 'CASCADE' option for cascade delete behavior. However, when I delete a Project, the associated Banners are not being deleted as expected.
Here's how I've defined the associations in Sequelize:
// Inside db.ts

db.Projects.hasMany(db.Banners, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
db.Banners.belongsTo(db.Projects);

// Other associations...

My controler for deleting a project
async function deleteProject(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const project = await db.Projects.findByPk(id);

    if (!project) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Project not found" });
    }

    await project.destroy({  cascade: true, force: true, where: { id }});
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Project deleted successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deleting project:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Could not delete project" });
  }
}

I've also ensured that foreign key constraints are properly set up in the database schema, and the database engine (MySQL) supports cascade delete operations.
However, despite these configurations, cascade delete is not working as expected, and associated Banners are not being deleted when a Project is deleted.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
NOTE: I am using nodejs, typescript, sequalize and phpmyadmin on windows

Please show foreign key definitions from DB. Not working cascading delete has nothing to do with Sequelize (only to create proper FKs on using sync method).
